# find the value of the test statistic

Tags: probability, statistics

You decide to carry out a hypothesis test. Since before the sample was drawn you thought that, if
anything, the company was understating the calorie content, you decide to use a one-sided alternative
hypothesis. You wish to test the null hypothesis that the population mean calorie content is what the
company claims it to be. You feel that for the given scenario, a choice of significance level of $α = 0.05$
is appropriate.
**#9. Which one of the following best represents the hypotheses of the test?**

So I know I have to use the t test statistic and I know the formula is $\dfrac{\overline{X} - \mu_0}{s/\sqrt{n}}$. 
But I how do I find the values if I am not given any of them?

Comment: You wrote "Which one of the following", but you never told us what "the following" are. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

You are not being asked to compute any values.  The question is only asking you to identify the hypothesis for your statistical test.  Your scenario mentions that you wish to test the null hypothesis that the population mean calorie content is  what the company claims it to be.